# Apollo client fragments not embedding data

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

This is the first time I've ventured into fragments and I can't see where I'm screwing up, but it definitely isn't working! In GraphiQL it's working fine:

```
query Tasks($taskIds: [String]!) {
    tasks(taskIds: $taskIds) {
        ...taskDisplay
    }
}
fragment taskDisplay on Task {
    _id
    name
    description
    status
    children {
        _id
    }
}
```

Here's what's in my client app:

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const TASK_FRAGMENT = gql`
    fragment taskDisplay on Task {
        _id
        name
        description
        status
        children {
            _id
        }
    }
`;

export const TASKS = gql`
    query Tasks($taskIds: [String]!) {
        tasks(taskIds: $taskIds) {
            ...taskDisplay
        }
    }
    ${TASK_FRAGMENT}
`;
```

So, the server returns the data correct as I can see in the *Network* tab of Chrome, but the data received by the `useQuery` result is an empty object. What gives?

Using `@apollo/client@3.2.0-beta.2` (I have downgraded to 3.1.0 with same results)

#### EDIT:

Adding more info. My code is about as simple as it could be using a hook. Here's what's happening:

```
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { TASK_FRAGMENT } from "../pages/task/queries";

const ROOT_TASK_QUERY = gql`
    query Project($projectId: String!) {
        rootTask(projectId: $projectId) {
            ...taskDisplay
        }
    }
    ${TASK_FRAGMENT}
`;

const useProject = ({ variables }) => {
    return useQuery(ROOT_TASK_QUERY, {
        variables,
    });
};
export default useProject;
```

And this is just logging the query itself:

[image: Missing Data]

Comment: your returned data is missing the `__typename` field, might this be the cause?

Comment: OMG that's awesome. I had turned that off when I was learning Apollo 'cause I didn't see it's utility for what I was doing. That's exactly what it was. `const cache = new InMemoryCache({ addTypename: false });`

Comment: Post it as an answer and I'll mark it!

Comment: My pleasure, will do

Comment: Why does __typename need to be present for fragments to be embedded?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your returned data is missing the `__typename` field

Comment: 1.5 years later, you fixed my issue too! Much appreciated

Comment: Also 1.5 years later, and you solved my issue! Thanks!

Comment: It can also be that you've set `addTypename` in the Apollo options to `false`.

Comment: Can anybody explain why this is the case?

Comment: 3 years later for me!